# Has French fallen out of use?

Tags: futurama, languages

> *"This is my Universal Translator, although it only translate into an incomprehensible dead language"*

When Cubert speaks into it 'Hello', it responds 'Bonjour'.

Does this mean French is a dead language in the year 3000? Supposedly, this is revealed in *Space Pilot 3000*, but I can't find a reference.

Comment: Is [the obvious meaning of a joke] the meaning of the joke? Really?

Comment: I know that Futurama can have these throw-away jokes, and then the next episode there is some contradiction. I was more wondering if French is ever spoken again, or if it really is 'dead' (as well as being the butt of a joke.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, French is a dead language in the year 3000.

In addition to the universal translator, there's also a reference in the pilot where in the 1999 countdown to New Year's, the French say their number in French.  In the 2999 countdown to New Year's, they say their number in English.

[French is spoken a number of times throughout the series](http://theinfosphere.org/French_language), but in no more than passing phrases similar to what people can do today with Latin.

Comment: Interesting Fact: Fry may be the world's leading authority on the language. He even showed it off in Bender's Big Score when he dances around with Charles de Gaulle on his head. (Who was included only to have his hand shaken later [during a song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AexzqFLquG8).)

Comment: I wonder what the [Republic of French Stereotypes](http://theinfosphere.org/Republic_of_French_Stereotypes) speaks?

Comment: Well they're French Stereotypes so I'd say badly imitated French accented English since that's what most stereotypes tend to speak.